# User defined namespaces in ASPX script run at at server

Tags: vb.net, webforms, namespaces

I have a file in webroot named `myfile.vb` with a namespace, a class and a function:

```
  Namespace Postgressql
      Class pgworker
        Public Function readsql() As Object
            Return "SQL data"
        End Function
      End Class
  End Namespace
```

I have build the solution without errors.

I am now trying to use this namespace within my webform solution, in another ASPX file with this statement

```
<%@ Import Namespace = "Postgressql" %>
<script runat="server">
    Dim Result As Postgressql.pgworker = New pgworker
    Dim mydata = Result.readsql()
</script>
```

It is telling me that it can not find the namespace. How can I make this namespace available in my aspx file?

Comment: In the Visual Studio solution explorer, where does this file appear in the solution?

Comment: HI, i have placed both in the root, it did mention that it recommends to place it in some web_app dir, but since i would like to try to have the vb files within certain dir to capsulate certain "procedures", i tried it in the root. 
I also tried to rename it to startup.vb like using the signalR sample I have, but I would need other names, but by your remark, it sounds as if the NS in A VB file in a asp.net solution can be achieved.

Comment: This isn't about the file location on the web folder. This is about the solution explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: OK, sorry, they are all in the root, in physical and in solution explorer, one startup.vb and one aspx file,
the error error exactly is ".... it is not acceptable in this context because it is friend", I set the fucntions in the VB to friend, I also moved the file to the App_code dir again, but no result after building solution.

Comment: Got it. Answer coming in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the class `Public`:

```
Namespace Postgressql
    Public Class pgworker
        Public Function readsql() As Object
            Return "SQL data"
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Wow, thanxs, i did some research and found thsi page,
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ssivkumar/create-and-use-namespaces-in-VB-Net/

I do lots of testing on code, and by my experience, only about 10% of all code samples really seems to work, most of them have some very obvious flaws,